# OmniAuth and Oauth2 gem to auth with one site and access another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I have two apps which share the same secret and I authenticate using one of them, like so:

```
  def oauth_client
    @oauth_client ||= OAuth2::Client.new(ENV["OAUTH_ID"], ENV["OAUTH_SECRET"], site: 'http://accounts.ourco.com')
  end

  def access_token
    if session[:access_token]
      @access_token ||= OAuth2::AccessToken.new(oauth_client, session[:access_token])
    end
  end
```

is there a way to use the same oauth_client to access the "http://data.ourco.com" server for example?

I can then do the rest with having to cross authenticate the sessions in the background between data and accounts servers.

Comment: have you tried just to duplicate your code on both applications?

Comment: yes it the same app in both providers, infact i'm using the same repo on both staging and localhost